# Formal deformations of algebras over not necessarily commutative rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In Iain Gordon's survery article ["Symplectic reflection algebras"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~igordon/pubs/ICRAsurvey_dec9.pdf) the concept of formal deformations of algebras over semisimple artinian (not necessarily commutative) rings is summarized (chapter 2). Unfortunately, deformations are needed in this generality and there are a few general things I don't understand:

1. An algebra over a semisimple artinian $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $k$ is "defined" as a $k$-bimodule $A$ with a $k$-bimodule morphism $A \otimes_k A \rightarrow A$. Is this a standard definition and is it correct that there is no associativity or unity assumption? I could not find a single book defining an algebra over a not necessarily commutative ring.
2. In the definition of a formal deformation given in the survey there also seems to be no associativity or unity assumption. Is this a standard definition and does Hochschild cohomology also work in this setting with the same interpretation? My problem is that when I don't restrict my deformations to be associative or have a unit, I might get a lot more deformations.

Is there some literature discussing this in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

I recall your [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15107/algebra-unital-associative-algebra-better-terminology) on a related topic...

I am sure that associativity is assumed here (and just omitted because the audience is unlikely to think of any other algebras); as for unitality, won't it be preserved automatically exactly because of that yoga "when we deform A we don't want to deform k"?

Comment: I remember my question, but there it was about algebras over commutative rings. That's fine!

Comment: For associative rings there is some noncommutative deformation theory of Laudal but also a nice unpublished preprint of Michael Artin from 1994. Without associativity you would tend to have to big things to have useful artinianess; besides even in the commutative case the existence of the unit element in a ring is responsible for the fact that every artinian unital ring is also noetherian. 